# Unexpected memory consumption when removing and adding elements in a Python set

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, memory-leaks, set

I am working on a problem that requires heavy usage of *add* and *remove* operations over a set. The total size of the set remains constant (i.e. the same number of elements that have been removed are replaced later). However, I observed that memory consumption is increased over time.

This is a simplification of the code that produces the issue:

```py
import psutil, os

def mem():
    return psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2

print("START:", mem())
s = set()
for i in range(2000000):
    s.add((i, i))
print(f"FILLED WITH 'add()' ({len(s)} items):", mem())
for i in range(2000000):
    s.remove((i, i))
print(f"REMOVED ({len(s)} items):", mem())
for i in range(2000000):
    s.add((i, i - 1))
print(f"FILLED WITH 'add()' ({len(s)} items):", mem())
```

In my machine (Ubuntu 20.04, Python 3.8.5) this code produces the following output:

```
START: 11.76953125
FILLED WITH 'add()' (2000000 items): 261.9609375
REMOVED (0 items): 76.61328125
FILLED WITH 'add()' (2000000 items): 323.88671875
```

If I replace the set *s* with a new fresh set I obtain these values:

```py
import psutil, os

def mem():
    return psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2

print("START:", mem())
s = set()
for i in range(2000000):
    s.add((i, i))
print(f"FILLED WITH 'add()' ({len(s)} items):", mem())
for i in range(2000000):
    s.remove((i, i))
print(f"REMOVED ({len(s)} items):", mem())
s = set()
print(f"NEW SET:", mem())
for i in range(2000000):
    s.add((i, i - 1))
print(f"FILLED WITH 'add()' ({len(s)} items):", mem())
```

```
START: 11.7265625
FILLED WITH 'add()' (2000000 items): 261.91015625
REMOVED (0 items): 76.56640625
NEW SET: 12.5625
FILLED WITH 'add()' (2000000 items): 354.44921875
```

I am a bit confused about these memory increases.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I can see you are adding one extra element in tuple while adding the tuple to set in last loop

Comment: When I remove the extra element from the tuple, the memory size again becomes the same as before

Comment: I notice your are using ```os.getpid()``` to identify current process.  However the os docs indicate the command ```os.getpgid(pid)``` returns the process group id of the process with process id pid. If pid is 0, the process group id of the current process is returned.  I would suggest you change the call ```0s.getpid()``` to ```os.getpid(0)``` to be sure you are getting correct information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @PRAKHARKAUSHIK. Indeed, in the example I used (i, i - 1) to insert elements that are different than the original ones. As you pointed out if the same elements are inserted again the memory consumption does not increase. However, for my problem I always add elements that are different than the removed ones.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @itprorh66! I tried with `os.getpgid(0)` and I obtained the same results. I also checked the memory consumption of the process with *htop* and the values are the same as the printed ones.